# GetBaseException() works on localhost but is null after release

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception

I use global exception handler `Application_Error` in `Global.asax` to handle exceptions:

```
var exception = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
exception.GetBaseException();
```

When an exception is thrown on localhost everything works perfectly but after release, `exception.GetBaseException()` is null.

I was wondering what can cause it?